# Slow MP3 decoding on Android

Tags: android, mp3, signal-processing, decoding

I've been working on MP3 decoding in Android based from this [tutorial](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=231#comment-88285)

Somehow, it takes more than 1 minute to decode a 4:30 duration song which is totally unacceptable in my case. I've been trying to figure out what is the problem and looking for a way to improve the speed. Been searching over the internet for days and still couldn't figure out why because the resource is very limited. I think I'm totally stuck here since I couldn't get anything from research.

Can someone point out any information about processing MP3 file in Android? I am using Libmad to decode the MP3 file and port it to Android with NDK. Maybe someone can point out any alternatives for MP3 decoding. I appreciate any information about it, thank you very much.

Comment: I am new to android and i am working on concatenating mp3 files in my android app. Can you help me in how to decode two or more mp3 files and encode into one file. I have searched alot but found nothing helpfull. You said that you have done mp3 encoding and decoding in android . Can you share code snippet. It will be a great help . Thanx

Answer (score 1):

All answers you seek for are already on the tutorial page.

As he explains in the article the time it takes seems to be normal:

> I tested it with the song “Schism” by tool which is a 6:47min long
>   song, encoded at 192kbps. The file weights in at 9.31mb, pretty big
>   for an mp3 imo... Without any optimizations (thumb code, -O0,
>   -DFPM_DEFAULT == standard fixed point math in libmad, no arm assembler optimized fp math) decoding the complete files takes 184 seconds on my
>   Milestone.

Then he explains how he optimized it. You should follow the same steps:

> Holy shit, batman! If i eliminate the buffer.get( samples ) call that
>   gets down to 44 seconds! Incredible. Now i still thought that is way
>   to slow so i started adding optimizations. The first thing i did was
>   compiling to straight arm instead of thumb code. You can tell the NDK
>   toolchain to do so by placing this in the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
```

> With this enabled decoding takes 36 seconds. The next thing i did was
>   agressive optimization via -O3 as a CFLAG. That shaved off only 2 more
>   seconds, so nothing to write home about. The last optimization is
>   libmad specific. The config.h file i linked to above does not define
>   the fixed point math mode libmad should use. Now, when you have a look
>   at fixed.h of libmad you can see quiet some options for fixed point
>   math there. There’s also a dedicated option for arm processors that
>   uses some nice little arm assembler code to do the heavy lifting. You
>   can enable this by passing -DFPM_ARM as a CFLAG. Now that did wonders!
>   i’m now down to 20 seconds for decoding 407 seconds of mp3 encoded
>   audio. That’s roughly 20x real-time which is totally ok with me. The
>   song i chose is at the extreme end of the song length spectrum i will
>   have to handle in my next audio game project. A song a user uses will
>   be processed once and waiting for that 20 seconds is ok in my book.

And the most important part comes:

> ***I’m afraid i won’t release the source of the ported audio framework*** as
>   it’s a bit of a mess and would need some work to clean up.

And many people in the comments rant about the library and say that they gave it up in favor of [libmpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/api/)

Comment: I actually followed everything he did and there is no change. I followed everything because there was no other reference in the net, so this tutorial is my only source. I'm even using faster Android than his, so technically the decoding should be faster in my machine.

Comment: Additional note, his case and mine is slightly different. His case seems to be standalone audio application while mine is a sub-application inside an application. I'm not sure if this affects my processing speed.

Comment: Maybe you can try to increase the buffer size and check if it makes a difference.